# value from php EOT causing javascript map error

Tags: javascript, php, eot, mapsvg

trying to render mapSvg via value from php.

however having an issue when mapSvg trying to read value from php variable...

if I bring in php value into chosen_source, then and do this

```
jQuery('#map-'+chosen_source).mapSvg(
```

then this above line will trigger the mapsvg getComputedStyle error.

if I directly hardcode `jQuery('#map-newyork').mapSvg(`
then no error

if I declare `var chosen_source = 'newyork';`
then no error.

```
mapsvg.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at new MapSVG.ResizeSensor (mapsvg.min.js:1:746)
    at Object.setResponsive (mapsvg.min.js:3:2667)
    at Object.setSize (mapsvg.min.js:3:2119)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mapsvg.min.js:4:25190)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:29072)
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:79901)

<?php

$state = "newyork";

$printout = <<<EOT

    var view_width = jQuery("#content").width();
    var chosen_source = `{$state}`;
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 500;
    var vB = [map_source.get(chosen_source).get('vb_L')];

jQuery('#map-'+chosen_source).mapSvg(
    {width: w,
    height: h,
    source: "/map/"+ map_source.get(chosen_source).get('source') 
});
EOT;

echo $printout;
?>
```

anyone have solution on this?

Comment: in the code you're using backticks, not apostrophe or double quote. `var chosen_source = \`{$state}\`;`

Comment: hi, i tried "{$state}"  and '{$state}',  none working...

Comment: "none working" means? what's then in $state? If it's empty, then it is empty in the first place, meaning the PHP script that generated the Javascript is faulty.

Comment: I echo printout to front html page and it successfully load the map. however when view chrome console, it throw error mapsvg.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Windo..  Then I try debug by hardcoding jQuery('#map-newyork').mapSvg 
and remain map_source.get(chosen_source).get('source') and refresh again, the
chrome console no show error. So I narrow down to the jQuery('#map-'+chosen_source) this part causing chrome console error.